# Iterative Green's function analysis for wave equation with self-driving term

Tags: waves, terminology, perturbation-theory, greens-functions

I have the following wave equation:

$$
(\partial_t^2 -c^2 \partial_x^2) \bar{u} = f(\bar{u})
$$

I assume I can do the Green's function method such as:

$\square =  \partial_t^2 -c^2 \partial_x^2$

$$
\square\cdot G(\bar{x},t) = \delta(x,t)
$$

Such that the general solution is:

$$
\bar{u}(x,t) = \bar{u}_0(x)+ \int G(\bar{x},t)f(\bar{u})dxdt
$$

Which would then have to be solved iteratively and be cut off to at some point? Such as:

$$
\bar{u}(x,t) = \bar{u}_0(x)+ \int G(\bar{x},t)f\left[\bar{u}_0(x')+ \int G(\bar{x'},t')f(\bar{u})dx'dt'\right]dxdt  = \bar{u}_0(x)+ \int G(\bar{x},t)f\left[\bar{u}_0(x')\right]dx'dt'+ \int G(\bar{x},t)\left[\int G(\bar{x'},t')f(\bar{u})dx'dt'\right]dxdt
$$

Is this correct? Is there a name for this type of GF iteration? Is there a name for this type of wave equation?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of scattering theory in quantum mechanics, this approach applied to the Schrodinger equation is called the [Born series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_series). In order for the iteration to (approximately) converge in a finite number of steps, you want the driving force to be *weak*, so that $\bar{u}$ is approximately equal to a solution of the free wave equation. Then to reach a given precision you can stop a finite number of iterations; this is known as the [Born approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_approximation).

The wave equation with an arbitrary function of $u$ on the right hand side is equivalent to the [Klein-Gordon equation with a potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation#Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation_in_a_potential), which is usually written as
\begin{equation}
\square \phi + V'(\phi) = 0
\end{equation}
where $V(\phi)$ is the *potential*. (I am assuming $u$ is a scalar field).

Comment: Thank you so much! So does this Green's function series (Born Series) only work for weak potentials? What would be the result for a strong driving force?

Comment: @Ebar I think of it like a Taylor's series. The method should work if you do an infinite number of iterations, but it's only *useful* if you can get an accurate answer after a *finite* number of iterations. That only happens if the potential is weak. This is a typical property of iterative solutions; they will converge much faster if you start with a "good" guess that is close to the exact solution. Having a weak potential means you can start with a good guess since you know how to solve the equation when the potential is zero, and a weak potential only changes the solution by a small amount.